# su -s ignoring specified shell

Tags: raspbian, bash

Here is what happened: I used fish shell as default shell for pi account. I removed it but didn't change the default shell and now I am unable to log in. Luckily I have another account but it doesn't have sudo privilege (so I cannot just change `/etc/passwd` file).

I tried:

```
su --shell /bin/sh pi
```

or

```
su -s /bin/bash pi
```

So it won't try to use fish.

But it seems it is just ignoring the `--shell` option:

```
Password: 
Cannot execute /usr/bin/fish: No such file or directory
```

What else can I do to regain access to my pi account?

Comment: `su` just change the user, it is not the same as `sudo`. It doesn't need root permissions. You'll have to know the other user's password though. The "Password" out put was where I typed the pi user password. It worked, but it ignored my option to use sh shell and tried to use fish, which is not installed anymore

Comment: Those are the permission on my /bin/su

`-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 31092 Jun  5  2012 /bin/su`

Anyone can execute it. And I think it really wouldn't make sense otherwise.
Maybe what you mean is that one cannot `su` to root user, which is true indeed.

Comment: That is strange. I never modified it myself. Is this the default for Rasbian only? On my macbook it is also executable by anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems it is just ignoring the `--shell` option:
>
> ```
> Password: 
> Cannot execute /usr/bin/fish: No such file or directory
> ```

This is correct behaviour, as (most likely) you have not added `/usr/bin/fish` to the `/etc/shells`. Consider this explanation from `man su`:

> If the target user has a restricted shell (i.e. the shell field of this user's entry in `/etc/passwd` is not listed in `/etc/shells`), then the `--shell` option or the `$SHELL` environment variable won't be taken into account, unless `su` is called by root.

---

But to modify `/etc/shells` you need root permissions, so you are effectively locked out.

Your only option is to remove the SD card, mount it to another system, and modify the files accordingly (either `/etc/passwd` to regain access directly or `/etc/shells` to confirm the above).

Comment: This was what solved my problem. But mounting the sd card with NOOBS esoteric partitioning was a problem itself. I ended up finding a solution to it online and posted it as an answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/58395/57522).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `chsh`

Try

```
chsh -s /bin/bash pi
```

Comment: This is what I got :(

`You may not change the shell for 'pi'`